# Symfony 2 getter for DateTime returning string

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

I have a getter that is returning a string when I am expecting a DateTime.

> Argument 1 passed to semesterBreakweeks ... must be an instance of DateTime, string given

A string 2016-07-25 00:00:00 is returned.

The Doctrine definition is

```
/**
*
* @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
*/
protected $term_start_date;
```

The getter is

```
/**
* @return DateTime
*/
public function getTermStartDate() {
 return $this->term_start_date;
}
```

The setter is

```
/**
 * @param DateTime $term_start_date
 */
public function setTermStartDate(DateTime $term_start_date) {
  $this->term_start_date = $term_start_date;
}
```

The list of semesters is generated via

```
/**
* @return array
*/
public function findToAdd() {
  $q = $this->getEntityManager()
   ->getConnection()
   ->executeQuery("SELECT ss.*
        FROM source_semester ss
        LEFT OUTER JOIN semester s on s.term = ss.term_code
        where s.term IS NULL");

   return $q->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Unsw\CamsSourceDataBundle\Entity\SourceSemester");
}
```

The call is

```
$startDate = $sourceSemester->getTermStartDate();
$endDate = $sourceSemester->getTermEndDate();

// The number of break weeks is the number of weeks in the semester minus the days you get.
$break_weeks = $semester->semesterBreakWeeks($startDate, $endDate);
```

Comment: Which database are you using? Have you read: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/known-vendor-issues.html#datetime ?

Comment: can you show us your `setTermStartDate`?

Comment: How do you get the object: are you loading it from database or creating manually? If you create manually you can call `setTermStartDate` with whatever you want - if you set it with sting, you get string; if you set array - get array, \DateTime - \DateTime

Comment: I added the setter and the list of semesters is generated via a raw query also added.

Comment: You're using doctrine, yet in `findToAdd` you fall back to `executeQuery` (on the `\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection`) which will bypass all of doctrines *orm-magic*, including resolving configured types like `datetime`.

Comment: Yes - just sql. FetchAll does specify the class, but likely to be the problem looking at it.